# Is there any way via any API to track Metadata history?

Tags: metadata-api, metadata, debugging

I am using metadata API to retrieve the LastModifiedBy of an Object. But, it returns me only one User.

I wanted to know if we can track, the Users whoever modified the Object. Is it possible by any means?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Starting with **Winter'16** the [SetupAuditTrail object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_setupaudittrail.htm) has now been exposed via the **Salesforce API**'s and within **Apex** via **SOQL**. Its pretty much a mirror of the CSV download, accept for the Delegate User (though since this is documented, this could be a bug or something i'm missing). The following is a sample query [from my latest blog](http://andyinthecloud.com/2015/10/18/setup-audit-trail-api-in-winter16/) where i dig into it a little further...

```
List<SetupAuditTrail> stuffDoneByConsultants = 
    [SELECT Id,
        Action,
        CreatedBy.Name,
        CreatedDate,
        Display,
        Section 
     FROM SetupAuditTrail 
     WHERE CreatedBy.Email LIKE '%xyzconsulting.com%'];
```

Comment: Andrew - this is a great feature fr reporting!

Comment: Yes, SetupAuditTrail is SOQL'ble ie searchable. Metadata Search AppExchange app now supports searching Setup Audit Trails. View/Install app from https://goo.gl/qOJCIM. Disclosure : Apologies for self promotion :)

Answer (score 6):

I think you're looking for the Setup Audit Trail. This setup screen should display the last 20 metadata modifications, the last 6 months can be downloaded as csv.

```
Setup > Security Controls > View Setup Audit Trail
```

[image: View Setup Audit Trail]

**Update:** Apparently this data is not exposed/supported by the Metadata API (or  any other). There is an idea on the IdeaExchange on which you can vote: [Make Audit Setup Trail History available via the API](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000glm9AAA)

Comment: i want the same via metadata API. Is it possible through any other means, other than metadata? I need it in external application.

Comment: Sorry, did not pay attention to your tags, it may help if you explicitly mention that in your question. I interpreted "any means", as truly "any means".

Comment: hehe..no problem :)

Comment: I don't know the metadata/docs well enough to be certain what you want isn't possible so i'll leave that up to someone else.

Comment: Nope, still no API access for the setup audit trail AFAIK. See this Idea: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000glm9AAA

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can track all changes to salesforce through Audit Trial.
There are some tools available in appexchange like [AutoRABIT](http://www.autorabit.com) where we can track changes to all metadata memebers with given date and time. 
 By using advanced search options we can search by date,metadata type,modified user,component name etc.

[image]

Thanks,

Niranjan.