# Discrepancies between downloaded Setup Audit Trail and SetupAuditTrail query

Tags: soql, setup-audit-log

I have noticed that delegated user logins (i.e. when a managed package admin logs in via grant login access) show up in the downloaded setup audit trail, but do not show up in a SOQL query of the `SetupAuditTrail` object.  This is referenced in the previous question [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/29323/is-there-any-way-via-any-api-to-track-metadata-history).  Is there any documentation for this discrepancy? The linked question's answer is unclear on this point, and I want to be able to document that using the query does not unintentionally exclude any other results.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be documented as a [known issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000eawwQAA).  Summary:

> Setup Audit Trail API not logging Login-As login event, only Login-As logout event

This is marked as having no fix, and unfortunately the workaround they suggest is getting the CSV via UI.

Comment: Note that the issue has been fixed as suggested by mentioned link.

Comment: @metasync What link?  Because the known issue I linked to still has it marked as "No Fix".

Comment: Nevermind, I misunderstood the status  icon. I was trying to process some customer data and noticed Login-As events. So thought it might have been fixed.